# ARM Template for Iot Hub with IoT Edge device

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-rm-template, azure-iot-edge

I need to deploy an Azure IoT Hub with an IoT Edge device by using ARM Templates. Unfortunately, I cannot find any property for the Edge device object in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.devices/iothubs). Should I assume that this feature isn't supported yet?

**UPDATE:** I finally managed to create the IoT Edge Device by using Azure CLI with [IoT Extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-cli-extension) `az iot hub device-identity create --hub-name hubName --device-id newEdgeDevice --edge-enabled`

Answer (score 3):

Do not know if it is supported but what you could do is attach a device by hand and have a look in https://resources.azure.com. If is shows up there it should be possible.

If you need any assistance please let me know.

Comment: I have never used Resource Explorer before, it's a nice tool thank you.
Should I check the ARM template generated by the tool? From what I have seen, it seems to be same I saw in the Azure Portal, which doesn't contain any device.

Comment: Hi, if it does not contain the devices I think the option isn't supported yet.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know any other way to create the device automatically? I couldn't do it neither using Azure CLI nor Powershell.

Comment: I finally managed to create the IoT Edge Device by using Azure CLI with [IoT Extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-cli-extension)
`az iot hub device-identity create --hub-name hubName --device-id newEdgeDevice --edge-enabled`

Comment: @user2297037 I'd recommend you turn your last comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Azure CLI command is as discussed before

```
az iot hub device-identity create --hub-name hubName --device-id newEdgeDevice --edge-enabled
```